# Why does this return true?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I recently started to teach myself Java, after playing around with CodingBat I am left with an extremely basic question. Why is this returning "true"?

```
a = 1, b= -1, negative = true

public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
  if(!negative && a <= 0 && b >= 0 || a >= 0 && b <= 0){
    return true;
  }else if(negative && a <= 0 && b <= 0){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Well have you at least debugged into the code to see *which* return statement it's hitting?

Comment: because a >= 0 and b <=0.

Comment: just as @SedrickJefferson said. the && is ignored after ||.

Comment: Hint: look up the precedence of `||` and `&&`.

Comment: First thing you can do is debug. To know exactly what are going wrong. Then i think that you can try to use some of this ().
Example:
'if(!negative && (a <= 0 && b >= 0 || a >= 0 && b <= 0))'

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

In:

```
!negative && a <= 0 && b >= 0 || a >= 0 && b <= 0
```

the higher precedence of `&&` than `||` means it is the same as:

```
(!negative && a <= 0 && b >= 0) || (a >= 0 && b <= 0)
```

The [conditional-or operator (`||`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24) will return true if either of its operands are true:

- `!negative && a <= 0 && b >= 0` is false, because `negative` is false (as is `b >= 0`, but that's not evaluated);
- `a >= 0 && b <= 0` is true

Hence the expression is `true`, and so the if statement is executed, meaning that `true` is returned.

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

because :

```
if (!negative && a <= 0 && b >= 0 || a >= 0 && b <= 0) {
//---(false)------(true)----(false)-----(true)----(true)
```

The trick is with `||` :

```
false && true && false -> false
true && true -> true
```

---

```
(false && true && false) || (true && true) ----> true
     false               ||     true       ----> true
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first if
`if(!negative && a <= 0 && b >= 0 || a >= 0 && b <= 0){`
A is greater than 0, and b is less than 0, so return true.